# How to find a minimum value in a 2D array without using numpy or flattened in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say that:

```
atable = [[6, 2, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 8, 7, 6], [8, 9, 3, 7]]
```

without using numpy or flattened, how would you find the minimum value of the entire list?

I assume you can use a list but I am not sure.

Comment: Try to make a code out of your assumptions, then maybe we could understand your intentions better. Plus, SO is not a code writing service if you want to get a proper answer for your question it's better to add the code that you've tried before and explain more about your expected output and the reasons that you don't want to use certain solutions.

Comment: Are you working with an array or a list?

Answer (score 2):

Here are several approaches:

```
from itertools import chain

atable = [[6, 2, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 8, 7, 6], [8, 9, 3, 7]]

# Flatten the sublists into a single list
result = min(chain.from_iterable(atable))

# Find the min of each list, the find the min of mins
result = min(map(min, atable))

# Use a generator expression with nested loops
result = min(i for lst in atable for i in lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force approach:

```
atable = [[6, 2, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1], [4, 8, 7, 6], [8, 9, 3, 7]]
min_list = []
for l in atable:
    min_list.append(min(l))
min_val = min(min_list)
```

Answer (score -1):

For your specific problem...

```
min(min(a_table))
```

As noted by @Prune this does not work. In fact min(a_table) returns the sublist with the smallest first element.

Comment: This doesn't work; change atable[1][0] to 13, and it returns `4` from the third element.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'll adapt the response. Weird behaviour though.
For the record, the wrong solution was min(min(atable)).

Comment: The behaviour is well-defined: it compares the lists, element by element, until it finds a difference.  Think it terms of sorting the lists.